# Get the unquoted value of a string variable inside of aes() call

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, aesthetics

I would like to generate a hovertext for `ggplotly()` using `aes()` along the lines of

```
mapping <- aes(text = paste0(
    "Value: ",
    columnName
))
```

where `columnName` is a variable containing a column name as a string. Now, I don't want `columnName` recognized as a column name itself. If `columnName == "col1"` the result I want is

```
aes(text = paste0(
   "Value: ",
    col1
))
```

which evaluates to the aesthetic mapping `` `text` -> `paste0("Value: ", col1)` ``.

I have tried using `aes_string()`, but

```
columnName <- "col1"
aes_string(text = paste0(
    "Value: ",
    columnName
))
```

just evaluates to the aesthetic mapping `` `x` -> `Value:col1` ``.

How do I make this work?

Comment: I don't understand what your expected result is.

Comment: If ```columnName``` has the value e.g. ```col1```, I want ```aes(text = paste0("Value: ", col1)```.

Comment: Yes, I read that. Problem is that it doesn't make any sense (if you understand ggplot2 and R). Do you want to create an unevaluated expression?

Comment: I would like the variable ```columnName``` evaluated and the value (a string) unquoted.

Comment: It makes sense because ```col1``` will evaluate to the column ```data$col1``` which, by value recycling, makes ```paste0("Value: ", col1)``` evaluate to ```c("Value: value1", "Value: value2", ...)``` inside of the ```ggplot()``` call if ```data$col1``` contains the value ```c("value1", "value2", ...)```. Does this clear your question?

Comment: Are you looking for `columnName <- as.name(columnName);
mapping <- bquote(aes(text = paste0(
  "Value: ",
  .(columnName)
))
)`? Obviously it needs to be `eval`uated later on. (I'm sure there is something similar and fancy in the tidyverse hell.)

Comment: Yes, this is just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently OP wants to create an expression object in order to evaluate it later on. That can be achieved using `bquote` (or `substitute` or some function from the tidyverse wich probably involves exclamation marks):

```
columnName <- "col1"
columnName <- as.name(columnName) #first turn the character string into a quoted name
mapping <- bquote(aes(text = paste0(
  "Value: ",
  .(columnName) #this substitutes the name into the expression
))
)
#aes(text = paste0("Value: ", col1))
```